# Does apple support core plot framework? Can we use googlecode repository source codes?

Tags: core-plot

I have a doubt if apple is supporting coreplot framework in it's application. Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 0):

core plot is an open source framework lead by the guys from MacResearch.org

It is not an internal apple framework, however apple did provide them some support at WWDC by promoting the project.

If you have any questions for them why don't you ask them on their google groups list?